# What is this operator, "??"

Tags: c#, dll, syntax, nullreferenceexception

I'm on an upgrade project and recently began experiencing issues with the upgraded version of a DLL. I decompiled the original dll and found the following if statement:

```
if (fieldConfiguration == null && Context.ContentDatabase != null)
{
    Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.SelectSingleItem(
        string.Format("//*[@@templateid='{0}' and @@key='{1}']", 
            (object) TemplateIDs.TemplateField, (object) fieldName));
}
```

I then decompiled the upgraded version of the DLL and the statement was as follows:

```
if (fieldConfiguration == null && (Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database) != null)
{
    Item obj = Context.ContentDatabase.SelectSingleItem(
        string.Format("//*[@@templateid='{0}' and @@key='{1}']", 
            (object) TemplateIDs.TemplateField, (object) fieldName));
}
```

I was able to step through the code by decompiling the DLLs with dotPeek and using the dotPeek symbol server functionality. I can see that the code is failing when using the upgrade DLL because Context.ContentDatabase is null. What I don't understand is how that double ternary operator is evaluated. Could someone clarify for me what's going on there? It seems as though the creators of this assembly wanted a null check for Context.ContentDatabase but may have made a mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you calling the binary null-coalesce operator (`??`) "ternary"?

Comment: Yep, didn't know that's what it was called haha

Comment: So "double ternary" means "Two question marks"? Unary means there's one of something, binary means two of something, ternary means three, quaternary should be obvious.

Comment: Yes, that double question mark operator: Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database

Comment: "The ternary operator" in C-like languages such as C# is `a ? b : c` -- the conditional operator, which has three operands, hence the name.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how to google "??", but you could certainly google "C# operators" and read the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yeah that looks like an error. The code is looking whether `Context.ContentDatabase` or `Context.Database` aren't `null`, and then continues to use the former, even if it was `null`.

The code should look like this:

```
var database = Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database;

if (fieldConfiguration == null && database != null)
{
    Item obj = database.SelectSingleItem(
        string.Format("//*[@@templateid='{0}' and @@key='{1}']", 
            (object) TemplateIDs.TemplateField, (object) fieldName));
}
```

Where it stores the database in a separate variable using the null-coalescing operator and then operates on that, if it isn't `null`.

So you should contact the team who provides this library and file a bug with them.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I thought was going on based on my debugging but wanted a second opinion before raising the red flag. Looks like a learned a new operator too!

Comment: This is in a 3rd party dll, so I assumed he doesn't have governance over it. It is possible though to compile an assembly after decompilation + modification, I've done it in the past. But that can be a dead end if you have to release the software or you violate any rights.

Answer (score 0):

`(Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database)` expressions end result is `Context.ContentDatabase` if Context.ContentDatabase is not null, otherwise it'll be `Context.Database`. The null-coalesce operator is a step forward to terse `null` checks.

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Context.ContentDatabase and Context.Database are same types. The below code should work.

```
var contentDatabase = Context.ContentDatabase ?? Context.Database;
if (fieldConfiguration == null && contentDatabase != null)
{
Item obj = contentDatabase.SelectSingleItem(
    string.Format("//*[@@templateid='{0}' and @@key='{1}']", 
        (object) TemplateIDs.TemplateField, (object) fieldName));
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the source code in this instance but I can definitely send this along when I raise the red flag. Thanks!